# h5py: IOError: unable to open file (File accessibilty: Unable to open file)

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a problem with opening a hdf5 database in python working on an ubuntu-system. The hdf5-file was created with `with h5py.File('abs_path','w') as file_hdf5:` so it should be closed after leaving the `with`-scope. It also worked to create it with

```
file_hdf5 = h5py.File('abs_path','w')
#some changes
file_hdf5.close()
```

I checked the database with `hdfview` tool and everything looked fine, so seems to be successfully created.
But some code lines later I try to open the hdf5 database with

```
file_hdf5 = h5py.File('abs_path','r')
```

and it failed with

```
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 71, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1709)  
IOError: unable to open file (File accessibilty: Unable to open file)
```

Also

```
with h5py.File('abs_path','r') as file_hdf5:
```

is failing with the same error.
Has somebody an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: How about this: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/332

Comment: Thanks that helped. I set the file-open-mode to 'a'. But I don't understand why I can't open a closed file in an arbitrary mode.

Comment: Andrew Collette (main author of h5py) says there that it's consistent with the behaviour of hdf5. I don't understand the behaviour as well.

Comment: Could you solve the issue ? Your solution is appreciated.

Comment: See the first two comments.